# Latency effects of routes.js in sails.js project

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to determine if the routes.js can cause bad response times if used, or used incorrectly. Due to bad response times in our load tests.
We are using routes.js to load views and to route a request to a controllers method (for db queries).

Load views example:

```
'GET /' : {view: 'mainframe'}
```

route request example:

```
'GET /main_edit' : {controller:'MainController', action:'edit', skipAssets: true}
```

We have about 30 different 'routes'.

I came across a post by [netflix](http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/nodejs-in-flames.html) which seems to suggest the routes can give a problem due to array that it uses for hold routes. The way they use routes seems different to the above though.

Using: node.js v5.6.0 and sails.js  0.12.0